# Is there a way to have an option that can run all previous cases in a switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

For example, if the user selects option 1 - 3 it does their own specific task. If user enters 4, it does all options 1 - 3. Is there a way to accomplish this using switch statement without having to copy and paste all code from each of the cases?

```java
switch (option) {
    case 1: {
        System.out.println("1");
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        System.out.println("2");
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        System.out.println("3");
        break;
    }
    case 4: {
        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("2");
        System.out.println("3");
        break;
    }
    default: {
        System.out.print("Invalid selection.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Break conditionally. Put 4 at the top.

Comment: While @BoristheSpider's suggestion would work, I think it is ugly and confusing. Just have a single method call in each of cases 1 2 and 3, and duplicate the three calls in case 4.

Comment: You might find https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device interesting.

Comment: Hi @M. Ruiz, You may have only those four conditions only right, We can use continue along with flag management to resolve the issue. as per you above code. If you have any dynamic logic we need concern about it.

Comment: Why would you need that just for some print statements? If you're talking more complex code, move the code to **methods**, then call the methods. Methods allow code re-use.

Comment: @Andreas you realize this is just as an example, right? I am asking a question on how to call code from the previous cases, not asking anything about print statements. For the sake of simplicity, I put simple code.

Comment: @M.Ruiz You realize I already address that too in my comment, right?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I implemented your code and while it works, it seems a little hacky. You put conditional breaks on all except the last case before the default case. Works, but doesn't seem like the best implementation.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen continue only works inside of loops, doesn't work in a switch case statement unfortunately.

Comment: @M.Ruiz I know. I thought it might interest you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`switch` statement does not allow repeated `case`'s, so requested functionality may be achieved only with multiple `if` statements using OR operation:

```java
if (option == 1 || option == 4) {
    System.out.println("1");
}
if (option == 2 || option == 4) {
    System.out.println("2");
}
if (option == 3 || option == 4) {
    System.out.println("3");
}
```

---

Another approach could consist in preparing a map of options to certain actions or lists of actions to implement required logic.

1. `Map<Integer, Runnable>` + `Predicate.or`

```java
// define a map of simple actions
static final Map<Integer, Runnable> actionMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
static {
    actionMap.put(1, ()-> System.out.println("1"));
    actionMap.put(2, ()-> System.out.println("2"));
    actionMap.put(3, ()-> System.out.println("3"));
};

public static void runOption(Integer option) {
    if (option < 1 || option > 4) {
        System.out.println("No action found for option = " + option);
    } else {
        Predicate<Integer> is4 = (x) -> 4 == option;
        
        actionMap.keySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(is4.or(option::equals))
            .map(actionMap::get)
            .forEach(Runnable::run);
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
IntStream.range(0, 6).boxed().forEach(MyClass::runOption);
```

Output:

```
No action found for option = 0
1
2
3
1
2
3
No action found for option = 5
```

2. `Map<Integer, List<Runnable>>` with `getOrDefault`

This method facilitates any composition of actions, not only having *one* action to run all available actions.

```java
static Runnable 
    action1 = ()-> System.out.println("1"),
    action2 = ()-> System.out.println("2"),
    action3 = ()-> System.out.println("3");

static final Map<Integer, List<Runnable>> actionListMap = Map.of(
    1, Arrays.asList(action1),
    2, Arrays.asList(action2),
    3, Arrays.asList(action3),
    4, Arrays.asList(action1, action2, action3)
);

public static void runOptionList(Integer option) {
    actionListMap.getOrDefault(
        option, 
        Arrays.asList(() -> System.out.println("No action found for option = " + option))
    )
    .forEach(Runnable::run);
}
```